# How do I create a list that contains all possible combinations of 3 elements with replacement?

Tags: python, graph-theory, combinatorics

I have the alphabet ['Q', 'W', 'E'] and I need to create a list that contains all the possible 3-letter combinations of the elements with replacement of the letters, i.e, ['QQQ', 'QQW', 'QQE', ... , 'EEW', 'EEE']

Comment: You should really consider a search first.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import itertools
["".join(t) for t in itertools.product(['Q', 'W', 'E'], repeat=3)]
```

This produces:

```
['QQQ', 'QQW', 'QQE', 'QWQ', 'QWW', 'QWE', 'QEQ', 'QEW',
 'QEE', 'WQQ', 'WQW', 'WQE', 'WWQ', 'WWW', 'WWE', 'WEQ',
 'WEW', 'WEE', 'EQQ', 'EQW', 'EQE', 'EWQ', 'EWW', 'EWE',
 'EEQ', 'EEW', 'EEE']
```